# Get index of a value in a table which already has a key (pick a random key/value pair)

Tags: lua

I'm looking to pick a random key/value pair from a table, but using `math.random()` doesn't work.

```lua
--intialises randomization
math.randomseed(os.time()+30) --sets a random seed based on the time
math.random(); math.random(); math.random(); --clears presets

local phrases = {
["a"] = 3
["b"] = 7
["d"] = 4
["f"] = 8
["p"] = 5
}

local phrase = phrases[math.random(1,5)]
```

`phrase` would always output as `nil`. Is there a method of getting the index to use with `math.random()` or an alternate method I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`math.random(1, 5)` returns numbers from 1 to 5. Your keys are strings.

You could create a table (as in: array - integer keys), get a random key from there and then access the `phrases`:

```lua
local phrases = {
  ["a"] = 3,
  ["b"] = 7,
  ["d"] = 4,
  ["f"] = 8,
  ["p"] = 5
}

local keys = {}

for k in pairs(phrases) do
  table.insert(keys, k)
end

local random_key = keys[math.random(1,5)] -- One of: "a", "b", "d", "f", "p"
local phrase = phrases[random_key] -- One of: 3, 7, 4, 8, 5
```

Comment: Follow-up: how would I print the selected key's phrase, e.g print `f` by randomly picking `4`? (right now, I'm getting a number out)

Comment: @Corsaka Edited the answer a little bit, does it answer your question from comment?